# How to rewrite categories url in htaccess or urlManager for yii2 classified ads website?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2, yii-url-manager

I am having issues with duplicated pages for seo , i think that the website when i make a categoy creates an original url then creates a duplicate of that url with the slug ,because i will find myself with 2 url that point to same category one is with slug (seo-frindly) and the other one without !

When the user click on a category it will get the seo-friendly url ,but since the other url is still working ,even if it's not displayed anyware,google detects it somehow and shows that i have duplicates

I would like to rewrite urls from

> `example.com/category?slug=categoryName`

to

> `example.com/category/categoryName`

Any suggestions will be very appreciated !!

I tried many codes in `htaccess` but with no result ,unfortunatelly i am not familiar with php or yii2 framework and didn't even tried to modify `urlManager` in web.php to avoid making more damage than good :)

This is my actual `htacces` code :

```
#Redirect www to non-www 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

# BEGIN rewrite rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /
               
 # ADMIN APP
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin(/.*)?$
    RewriteRule admin/.* admin/index.php            
   
 # FRONTEND APP
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
    RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
# END rewrite rules

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # mod_headers, y u no match by Content-Type?!
        <FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|svgz|ico|webp)$">
        SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

And this is my `urlManager` code :

```
urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'search' => 'site/search',
                'contact' => 'site/contact',
                '<controller:conversation>/<action:delete>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:conversation>/<action:reply>/<conversation_uid:[a-z0-9_\-]+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:account>/<action:invoices>/<page:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:account>/<action:conversations>/<page:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:listing>/<action:index|update|package|preview>/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                'page/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>' => 'pages/index',
                '<controller:category>/<action:location|map-view|get-map-location>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                [
                    'pattern' => 'category/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>/<page:\d+>',
                    'route' => 'category/index',
                ],
                [
                    'pattern' => 'category/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>',
                    'route' => 'category/index',
                ],
                [
                    'pattern' => 'category/map-view/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>/<page:\d+>',
                    'route' => 'category/map-view',
                ],
                [
                    'pattern' => 'category/map-view/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>',
                    'route' => 'category/map-view',
                ],
                [
                    'pattern' => 'store/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>/<page:\d+>',
                    'route' => 'store/index',
                ],
                [
                    'pattern' => 'store/<slug:[a-z0-9_\-]+>',
                    'route' => 'store/index',
                ],
                '<url:.+/>' => 'site/redirect'
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Enable strict parsing on the configuration.

If you change the `enableStrictParsing` line the `urlManager` configuration to

```php
'enableStrictParsing' => true,
```

The requests that don't use one of the URLs defined on the configuration will receive 404 as response, so the *duplicate* URLs like `example.com/category?slug=categoryName` will not be any longer valid.

The [Yii2 docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlmanager#$enableStrictParsing-detail) for that method say:

> Whether to enable strict parsing. If strict parsing is enabled, the incoming requested URL must match at least one of the $rules in order to be treated as a valid request. Otherwise, the path info part of the request will be treated as the requested route. This property is used only when $enablePrettyUrl is true.

Keep in mind that you will need to define rules for **all** URLs that need to be accessible, that means, for example, that `example.com` will not be directed by default to `site/index` and will instead return a 404.

An example rule that would fix that would be

```php
'/' => 'site/index',
```

The Yii2 docs have a very detailed [article](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing) about routing that includes an extensive section on creating rules.

Comment: thx for the answer but i don't have the knowledge to define the rules ! could you make an example for how should i direct example.com to site /ndex, and i will try to follow for the other url

Comment: @David see my edit. It looks like you have already defined the rules in the configuration, once you add the `site/index` rule, for example before `'search' => 'site/search',` everything should be working as expected.

Comment: @David If you found this answer useful and want to say thanks, do it by [marking the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and/or voting on it. See in the help pages why [voting is important](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).